# Getting null values for Azure Table query results

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I run this query:

```
string pkFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", 
QueryComparisons.Equal, pk);

TableQuery<DBDataSet> query = new TableQuery<DBDataSet>
().Where(finalFilter);

var list= table.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

It returns the expected entities but only shows null values for all properties other than primary key, row key, and time stamp. I use this same type of query on a different table and it works great. I created this new table containing DBDataSet and now I cannot retrieve the data. I have checked the table directly and all the values get inserted with no issue.

Here is DBDataSet:

```
public class DBDataSet: TableEntity
{
    public DBDataSet()
    {

    }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
}
```

Has anyone came across this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

OK! I made a dumb mistake but I will post an answer in case anyone else decides to make this same mistake. I passed in the wrong table for this query. When I switched the query type to DBDataSet, I forgot to switch the table. I did not get an exception or any warnings so this is why I was confused. Azure just tried to give me all the data it could match up. WOW... I hate these kinds of mistakes haha.